# SQL Agent Backup script

Tags: sql-server

Afternoon all,
Created the following Agent step script to backup a DB if the instance is primary (as it will fail on a synchronous commit secondary)......anyone see any bad in it?

```
DECLARE @name   VARCHAR (150)
DECLARE @path   VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @time   DATETIME
DECLARE @year   VARCHAR (4)
DECLARE @month  VARCHAR (2)
DECLARE @day    VARCHAR (2)
DECLARE @name   VARCHAR (2)
DECLARE @name   VARCHAR (2)
DECLARE @PathWithName VARCHAR (500)
DECLARE @Role_Desc VARCHAR (20)

--Check role.....
--IF( HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME ('sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states', 'OBJECT', 'execute') = 1)
IF (sys.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica('WSS_Content') = 1)  --Primary ready for backup
BEGIN
  -- Could be Primary or Secondary.....if Secondary Abort Backup
  IF EXISTS( SELECT hars.role_desc FROM sys.DATABASES d INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states hars ON d.replica_id = hars.replica_id WHERE hars.role_desc <> 'SECONDARY' ) 
    BEGIN
      SET @path = 'E:\MSSQL\Backups\xxxxxxxx\'  -- Put the name of the Folder in the xxxxx area MAKE SURE TO CREATE FIRST
      SELECT @time = GETDATE();  -- Pull current system date and time vectors
      -- Parse @time into Vars to use later in name creation
      SELECT @year = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (4), FORMAT (DATEPART(yy, @time), '000') ) )
      SELECT @month = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (2), FORMAT (DATEPART(mm, @time), '000') ) )
      SELECT @day = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (2), FORMAT (DATEPART(dd, @time), '000') ) )
      SELECT @hour = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (2), FORMAT (DATEPART(hh, @time), '000') ) )

      --Set the full filename with path e.g.  drive, folder and filename with date&time  
      SET @PathWithName = @path + @name + '.bak'

      -- Run the backup, with Copy_only, compress the DB, and do a page checksum
      BACKUP DATABASE[set DB name here]  -- Easily copied and paste form SSMS to avid typos
      -- Concatenate all into a var for TO DISK use
      TO DISK = @PathWithName  WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, SheckSum

      -- Back up completed now verify the backup file for errors
      RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK @PathWithName
    END  -- End if Either single instance or Primary replica
  ELSE
    -- Secondary replica, not ready for backup
    THROW 50000, 'This is not the primary replica.', 1
```

Comment: wow what happened to my format during the posting?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of creating your own custom code, make use of the open source scripts from Ola Hallagren:

> The SQL Server Maintenance Solution comprises scripts for running
> backups, integrity checks, and index and statistics maintenance on all
> editions of Microsoft SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server
> 2012, SQL Server 2014, SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2017, and SQL
> Server 2019.  The solution is based on stored procedures. The solution
> has been designed for the most mission-critical environments, and it
> is used in many organizations around the world. The SQL Server
> Maintenance Solution has been voted as Best Free Tool in the 2013,
> 2012, 2011, and 2010 SQL Server Magazine Awards.

You can configure this for your AlwaysOn environment also. See the article Brent Ozar wrote about this.

Links:

1. [Ola Hallengren scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/)
2. [Brent Ozar: Configure Always on AG
   backups](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/how-to-configure-alwayson-ag-backups-with-ola-hallengrens-scripts/)

Comment: Great script, 
but a huge overkill for what I need to accomplish, what is needed is backing up 1 DB within an AG one time out of normal backup cycle.  though Ola's script cover soup to nuts is a lot more then I needed which is ensure the backup is executed as with synchronous commit the secondary replica is not readable, my plan/need was to deploy this scrip on both instances and only execute on the current primary node and verify the created backup is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared @name twice:
DECLARE @name   VARCHAR (2)
DECLARE @name   VARCHAR (2)

You have a variable named @hour that hasn't been declared.
SELECT @hour = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (2).....

Otherwise, it looks fine.  Why not just use a maintenance plan though?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted, these are valid observations and advice.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure.  Maybe I should have put it in the comments instead.  The formatting is bad, too.

Comment: Thank for catching my overlooked double declare.